# Python vs Jinja Validation

Tags: python, authentication, flask, jinja2

What is the better way to check a user's state. Lets say I have a `halt` column in my database model:

```
halted = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
```

If I want to halt this users account, I would set the value to `true` / `1` and depending on this value certain content would not be open to him. Whats the best way to handle this?

`Python` code:

```
if user.halted == '1':
    return render_template('less_content.html')
```

`Jinja2` code:

```
{% if user.halted is True %}
<body> show less content...</body>
{% else %}
<body> show more content...</body>
{% endif %}
```

1. I mean is there a difference in terms of security?
2. When should be one method used over the other one?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, obviously? Return an entirely different template or `Forbidden` response from the server, or just alter the view that you send.

Answer (score 1):

There are no security implications because the template gets rendered in the backend and only the final result (without the hidden stuff) is sent to the browser.

I'd prefer the Jinja version because usually you only want one template for one thing instead of replicating the same thing in multiple files. That's error prone and cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem because most commonly we use the following in Jinja like `user.is_authenticated` to check if the user is logged in or not. This `user.halted` is no different than that. And for which method to use. Use Jinja when you can generalize html pages so that they you can reuse the same page instead of creating a new one like the less_content.html.

If you have more categories of users say, less_content, very_less_content and so on. Its better to generalize them and write them in a Jinja template. As it will save lot of rewriting the same HTML pages. Rendering them separately for each type of user will be lot of html pages. But it shouldn't matter much if you're talking about only 2 types of users i.e halted and not halted.